# How can i insert 1 row en sheet excel from R?

Tags: r, excel, xlsx, openxls

I´m new using the packages "xlsx":

```
wb <- xlsx::loadWorkbook(file = "test.xlsx")
sheets <- getSheets(wb)
sheet <- sheets[['0923301_']]
rows  <- getRows(sheet)#all rows
cells <- getCells(rows)#all cols
```

i want insert a row update values into 257,

[image]

other problem is only take A257, B257 and J257...i need A:H

`<main:c r=\"A257\" s=\"4\" t=\"s\">\r\n    <main:v>21</main:v>\r\n  </main:c>\r\n  <main:c r=\"B257\" s=\"4\"/>\r\n  <main:c r=\"C257\" s=\"4\"/>\r\n  <main:c r=\"J257\"/>\r\n</xml-fragment>}"`

function to insert row between two values in sheet on excel
or help to copy, remove and set values on excel from R.

Comment: UPDATE           
[1,] "2023" "Febrero" "14840" "102"   "154"   "14"     "4"     "5"